# What is a "distinguished automorphism" of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, definition

Math people:

The title is the question.  The reason I am asking is that I am trying to determine exactly what fields can be used for an inner product.  I posed that question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129413/what-fields-can-be-used-for-an-inner-product-space : if you have a comment about *that* question, please post it there and not here, lest anyone be accused of cross-posting.  I am posting this question here because I am certain that someone here will know the answer and I am afraid that if I post it at MathOverflow, someone will complain that it is not a "research-level question", which I suppose it isn't.

Wikipedia asserts that only $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ can be used as the basefield for an inner product, but their explanation is incomplete and self-contradictory.  They use the term "distinguished automorphism" without defining it or providing a link for its definition.  I have Googled the term and found nothing.  I know what an *automorphism* of a field is, but not a *distinguished automorphism*.

I am not an algebraist.  I took a semester of undergrad abstract algebra and have done a fair amount of reading on abstract algebra.  I would prefer a basic definition that does not involve differential geometry, differential topology, Lie groups, etc.  A reference in the form of a hyperlink or a book would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A distinguished automorphism is one that you distinguish. That is, the data that you're providing in some construction is not a field $F$ but a pair $(F, \alpha)$ where $F$ is a field and $\alpha$ an automorphism of it. $\alpha$ is the "distinguished" automorphism. As a more basic example of this terminology, suppose $(X, x)$ is a set $X$ and an element $x \in X$ of $X$. We might call such pairs "sets with distinguished points."

(You can also use the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) to construct Hilbert spaces.)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know people used the quaternions for this.  It sounds like something a physicist would do.  Can you provide a link or a reference?  The usual definition of "inner product" contains the word "field", and $\mathbb{H}$ is not a field because multiplication is not commutative.  So if you use quaternions to construct a "Hilbert space", will anyone split hairs and say it is not really a Hilbert space?

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, people usually use "field" in the definition of vector space, leaving aside inner products.

Comment: Yes, people do this in physics. Google "quaternionic Hilbert space," and see also http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/12/division_algebras_and_quantum.html . The definition of a vector space generalizes to division rings with no difficulty (consider left modules) and the theory is more or less the same; commutativity doesn't really help.